# lottery game probability

Tags: probability

In the "Make Money Game," the winning number is four digits, each selected at random from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, e.g. 0-3-9-6, 0-0-6-0, 9-4-7-9. A player may place any of the following types of bets. In each case tell the odds of the player winning.

I got,

```
1 digit in fixed position   such as *-*-3-*  probability is 1 in 10
2 digits in fixed positions such as 4 -*-6-*    probability is  1 in 100
3 digits in fixed positions such as 5-*-0-7 probability is 1 in 1000
4 digits - exact match  such as 2-0-0-1 probability is 1 in 100000
```

But i don't know how to approach these,

```
first 3 digits match in some order no duplicate digits among the three  
1-2-4-7 1st 3 any order matches 4-1-2-9       1 in  ?  

first 3 digits match in some order two digits the same among the three  1-2-2-7 
1st 3 any order matches  2-1-2-9    1 in   ?

4 digits match in some order no duplicate digits in bet 1-2-4-6 any order matches
2-6-1-4     1 in  ?

4 digits match in some order two digits the same in bet 2-2-4-6 any order matches
2-6-2-4      1 in   ?

4 digits match in some order two pair of digits in bet  2-2-4-4 any order matches
2-4-2-4      1 in   ?
```

For the first one, is it going to be (10,3)* (10,1) since first 3 digits math in some order no duplicate and the rest one we can choose whatever we want from [0,9]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'd say the probability is $6$ in $1000$ (since there can be
   $10^3=1000$ possible combinations for the first three digits and
   only the $3!=6$ permutations of our chosen numbers are "good"
   outcomes).
2. Similarly that would be $3$ in $1000$ ($1000$ combinations but
   this time only $3$ permutations).

(in these two cases the value of the fourth number were irrelevant)

3. $24$ in $10000$  (same thinking - $10^4$ possible outcomes, $4!$ "good" ones)
4. $12$ in $10000$
5. $6$ in $10000$

Is that clear enough? I can elaborate more if you'd like to. And your answer for the 4 digit exact match question doesn't seem right, though it's probably just a typo.

Comment: thanks! got it. It was a typo.

Comment: so for the last case,  there are C(4, 2) = 6 ways to place the smaller pair of digits. The larger pair then goes in the remaining places. The odds of winning are 6 in 10000? hummh

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easier way to do it you should try to create a python codelike this:

from random import randint
print(randint(1, 49))

I found a really cool [lucky numbers generator](http://www.lotterypros.com/lucky-number-generator/) on this site.